# Why was this 2011 question bumped to the front page?

Tags: support

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/280486/only-solid-color-possible-as-background-in-windows-7?answertab=votes#tab-top) appeared on the frontpage of Super User today.

The question, all comments, answers, etc., are all from '11. What caused it to be bumped up?

Comment: Bonus info: In the right side of the sidebar, it says *active today*. Click *today*, and it'll take you to the new or changed post (and show its ID in the URL). If there's no such post, it's already deleted. Earn 10,000 reputation and you can [see deleted posts](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (spoiler: You'll sometimes wish you couldn't :-) )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a new answer added today, but the answer was subsequently deleted by a moderator because it was just a "me too" comment, not an actual answer.